# How to calculate font height in WPF?

Tags: wpf, fonts, font-size

For a `FontFamily` how do I programatically retrieve/calculate the maximum height range for that font at a particular `FontSize`?

I need a value to set the height of a textblock that will display the font at the specified `FontSize` - this has to be carried out programatically.

I need a value that will take into consideration ascenders and descenders, etc.

**Update**

To clarify, I need the maximum height range for the entire `FontFamily`, not the height of some sample text in that font. I do not know what the text will be in advance.

Comment: Take a look at how TextBox calculates the height of the line [TextBox.GetLineHeight()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,f690fbc97792ace3)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The maximum height range for a font can be calculated using its [LineSpacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.linespacing.aspx) property which is a proportional figure for the font. This can be used to give a line height which can accommodate all glyphs for that font at a particular size.

```
    FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
    double fontDpiSize = 16;

    double fontHeight = Math.Ceiling(fontDpiSize * fontFamily.LineSpacing);
```

Result:

> ```
>    22.0
> ```

This figure will contain a small amount of [leading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) which is desirable when needing a height for rows of text (so that ascenders and descenders from adjacent rows of text have spacing).

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `Math.Ceiling()`?  I'm using Courier New size 12 and `textbox.FontSize * textBox.FontFamily.LineSpacing` gives **13.59375**.

Comment: No reason other than to work with whole numbers to reduce the chance that positioning other elements will not become blurry. If using the exact figure works for you, go for it.

Comment: Better to use `UseLayoutRounding="True"` than to lop off the decimal portion of the fontHeight, if reducing anti-aliasing is your goal.

Comment: You shouldn't use Math.Ceiling() when calculating the height of the TextBox line, because it depends on TextFormattingMode. See how [TextBox.GetLineHeight()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,f690fbc97792ace3) calculates that value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Windows.Media.FormattedText` class.

### Example:

```
FormattedText ft = new FormattedText("Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over A Lazy Dog.",
                                     CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                     CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                     new Typeface("Verdana"),
                                     9,
                                     new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
Double maxHeight = ft.MaxTextHeight;
```

Comment: Do you have an example of using this to say work out the height range for Verdana at 9pt? The question is not to work out the height of sample text, but for a FontFamily.

Comment: @decyclone But isn't that working out the maximum height of the sample text i.e. "Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over A Lazy Dog."?

Comment: What is the possibility of characters being used other than all the alphabets? For calculating Height, letter `H` in caps should be enough.

Comment: @decyclone That is not even an entire alphabet - that's just some English word characters and doesn't take into consideration scientific symbols, etc. It's not that simplistic unfortunately. I want something that will work against the whole FontFamily, not just sample text.

Comment: @decyclone French for example has capital letters with ascenders e.g. 'È'. That's taller than a capital H e.g. ÈHÈ.

Comment: @chibacity: That answer my question `What is the possibility of characters being used other than all the alphabets?`... I agree with you that this code won't help you with problem you mentioned.

Comment: @decyclone Yes, basing the measurement on sample text is not going to work for a variety of reasons - it's quite a thorny issue. Thanks for having a go though. :)