# Wpf- How can I get the LineHeight of a normal TextBox in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm working on a `CustomControl` that inherits from `TextBox` and can be re-sized by holding `Ctrl`while dragging the mouse, but sometimes when you re-size it, lines get cut off like this:

[image]

If this happens, I would like to adjust the chosen height, so that lines are not cut off. This is the code I have so far:

```
double LineHeight = ??;
double requiredHeightAdjustment = this.Height % LineHeight; 

                if (requiredHeightAdjustment != 0)
                {
                    this.Height -= requiredHeightAdjustment;
                }
```

**--Edit--**

In case anyone needs this in the future here is what I ended up with:

```
double fontHeight = this.FontSize * this.FontFamily.LineSpacing;

double requiredHeightAdjustment = this.Height % fontHeight;

var parent = this.Parent as FrameworkElement;

if (requiredHeightAdjustment != 0)
{
    double upwardAdjustedHeight = (fontHeight - requiredHeightAdjustment) + this.Height;

    if (requiredHeightAdjustment >= fontHeight / 2 && this.MaxHeight >= upwardAdjustedHeight
        && (parent == null || parent.ActualHeight >= upwardAdjustedHeight))
        this.Height = upwardAdjustedHeight;
    else
        this.Height -= requiredHeightAdjustment;
}
```

This solution also makes the smallest necessary change to the chosen `TextBox` size instead of always making a negative change.

Comment: You can invoke TextBox private method `lineHeight = (double)textBox.GetType().GetMethod("GetLineHeight", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(textBox, null);` or see how it is implemented [TextBlock.GetLineHeight .NET Reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/f690fbc97792ace3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your LineHeight is dependent on the font family and font size, you might want to look at the [GlyphTypeface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface%28VS.100%29.aspx) class in .NET 3.0+. It might be a bit too low-level though, but it has properties like `Height`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer led me to this answer about calculating font height: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509613/how-to-calculate-font-height-in-wpf

Comment: Can you also help in my case @http://stackoverflow.com/q/38520640/3170029

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked several years ago, but just in case anyone lands here searching for a solution, you can use `TextBlock.LineHeight` **attached property** to get `TextBox`'s `LineHeight`:

```
var LH = TextBlock.GetLineHeight(YOUR_TEXTBOX);
```

Comment: TextBox doesn't have `DependencyProperty LineHeightProperty` see implementation of [TextBlock.GetLineHeight](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock.cs,69bb0a18cce762d4). Your code not working.

Comment: @marbel82: LineHeight is an attached property and works perfectly fine with TextBox. Since it is an attached property, you cannot read or assign it directly. You must do it through TextBlock, both in XAML and in C#.

Comment: Using XAML to assign attached properties directly is pretty normal. I think you should include that portion of the code to make it clear what you intend.