# How To Get Caret Cursor Height In TextBox Using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, textbox, caret

I have some textBox having multiple line feature on with having different font size. Now I want to know the caret cursor height of this textbox text as its a simple text box so caret cursor will be able to resize as per font change etc and in other words I want to know the line height of the textBox or the font size of textBox.

```
int fontHeight ;
using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics()) {
float points = textBox1.Font.SizeInPoints;
fontHeight = Convert.ToInt16(points * g.DpiX / 72);
}
MessageBox.Show("myFont size in pixels: " + fontHeight );
```

And...

```
int fontHeight = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Font.Size);
```

For this I am using the above codes but not giving the full results so How to make it more perfect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying  some codes and snippets and edit them I got the below solution for every size of text that is shared below and its working perfectly.

```
int lineHeight;
using (Graphics g = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
{
    lineHeight = Convert.ToInt32(g.MeasureString("A", textBox1.Font).Height);
}
```