# Get "ascent" LineHeight from Font

Tags: c#, wpf

How can get the LineHeight of a Font given the FontSize?  It seems that it is different depending on the font and not necessarily connected to the FontSize.  I am using BlockLineHeight for the LineStackingStrategy.

**Clarification.**  I understand there are methods of determining the total line height.  In this case, I'm looking for the height from the baseline to the top of the font (so minus the tails of the p's etc.)

[image]

In the case of the picture above.  I want the ascent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509613/how-to-calculate-font-height-in-wpf

Comment: I would like the ascent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
ascent = fontFamily.GetCellAscent(FontStyle.Regular);
ascentPixel = font.Size * ascent / fontFamily.GetEmHeight(FontStyle.Regular);
```

from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `Graphics` object to draw on and have reference to, then you can do this.

```
Font myFont = new Font("Verdana", 15);
SizeF fontSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("my text", myFont);
```

This will then tell you the height and width of the string. You can use this for a singluar line to test the line height.

Or by this answer here: [How to calculate font height in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509613/how-to-calculate-font-height-in-wpf/4613711#4613711)
You can easily calculate the line height using some simple calculations.

Comment: What's e for the Graphics object?

Comment: When the Paint event is fired for a control it gets given `PaintEventArgs e`. e contains a Graphics object.