# How can I find the em height of a font in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, fonts

I am trying to calculate the height of a font given the font size in Silverlight ([similar to what this guy needed in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509613/how-to-calculate-font-height-in-wpf)). From what I gather, I need what is called the em height of the font. However, there does not seem to be any way to get this from the [FontFamily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) I am using; not is there any way that I can find to get the info to calculate it myself.

Are there any other methods to obtain this, in code?

I am using Century Gothic as my font, if that matters any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this [Charles Petzold MSDN Magazine article on Font Metrics in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335068.aspx), he discusses the lack of a `Font Metric Class` for Silverlight. He suggests using a TextBlock to get the text dimensions without rendering the text, but what may be of interest to you is he creates his own Font Metric Class, see if that works for you.

Comment: This looks like as close as I can get to a viable solution. Guess I will make it work! Thanks for the link!